# iOS: Margin bug in the question listing

Tags: bug, ios-app

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some of the questions in the list fall outside of the marginal divider. More specifically, it's the divider that appears to be oddly out of place.

This is the second time I've experienced this issue at the time of this update. Between occurances, the app has been closed, and the phone has been restarted, so I'd say the bug isn't related to some rare event.

iOS 7.0.4

Comment: Please use the [meta-tag:ios-app] to report issues with the iOS app.

Comment: 3:59 AM? What to say, we were talking about sleep spray some time ago...

Comment: @nicael 19 y/o human beings sleep during the day light, don't you know? ;)

Comment: @Sha What about you?

Comment: @nicael I sleep neither during day (work) nor during night (children). I think this makes me a vampire? :(

Comment: @Sha Wait, you are Shadow Wizard or Vampire?

Comment: @jt0dd What device and OS version are you using? just to check, is the device jail broken?

Comment: @Arie no, this is non jailbroken iOS 7.0.4

Comment: having trouble reproducing here. @jt0dd, Is this consistently reproducible on your end?

Comment: @Arie No. I look now and it is in place. I do not know what caused the occurance. Therefore, probably a rarity. I can't reproduce it. Check out that emoji bug. My app had just dealt with the emoji break around that time.

Comment: @Arie Correction: I have experienced the same bug again, however I still don't know what specifically causes it. See the question update; it's multiple questions this time.

Comment: Looks like this was an issue when using large Dynamic Type sizes